# portfolio filtering script needed

Tags: javascript, html, filtering, new-operator

I tried myself to do something in JS but didn't work out. would someone help me with a script that would filter the teammates based on their positions. i would later change them to departments ( eg: instead of Lead Developer, it'll be Web development team) so ill add more members, but i would like a way to filter them. Thanks in advance
PS. im really new to web developement , please be patient with me.

HTML

```
<section id="team" class="team">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
        
                    <div class="sec-title text-center wow fadeInUp animated animated" data-wow-duration="700ms" style="visibility: visible; animation-duration: 700ms; animation-name: fadeInUp;">
                        <h2>OUR INFLUENCERS</h2>
                        <div class="devider"><i class="fa fa-heart-o fa-lg"></i></div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="sec-sub-title text-center wow fadeInRight animated animated" data-wow-duration="500ms" style="visibility: visible; animation-duration: 500ms; animation-name: fadeInRight;">
                        <p>Connections with Key Influencer Profiles to accommodate diverse brand campaigns</p>
                    </div>

                    <!-- single member -->
                    <figure class="team-member col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 text-center wow fadeInUp animated animated" data-wow-duration="500ms" style="visibility: visible; animation-duration: 500ms; animation-name: fadeInUp;">
                        <div class="member-thumb">
                            <img src="img/team/member-1.png" alt="Team Member" class="img-responsive">
                            <figcaption class="overlay">
                                <h5>voluptatem quia voluptas </h5>
                                <p>sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit,</p>
                                <ul class="social-links text-center">
                                    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                                    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                                    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </figcaption>
                        </div>
                        <h4>John Filmr Doe</h4>
                        <span>Managing Director</span>
                    </figure>
                    <!-- end single member -->
                    
                    <!-- single member -->
                    <figure class="team-member col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 text-center wow fadeInUp animated animated" data-wow-duration="500ms" data-wow-delay="300ms" style="visibility: visible; animation-duration: 500ms; animation-delay: 300ms; animation-name: fadeInUp;">
                        <div class="member-thumb">
                            <img src="img/team/member-2.png" alt="Team Member" class="img-responsive">
                            <figcaption class="overlay">
                                <h5>voluptatem quia voluptas </h5>
                                <p>sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit,</p>
                                <ul class="social-links text-center">
                                    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                                    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                                    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </figcaption>
                        </div>
                        <h4>Martin Matrone</h4>
                        <span>Lead Developer</span>
                    </figure>
                    <!-- end single member -->
                    
                    <!-- single member -->
                    <figure class="team-member col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 text-center wow fadeInUp animated animated" data-wow-duration="500ms" data-wow-delay="600ms" style="visibility: visible; animation-duration: 500ms; animation-delay: 600ms; animation-name: fadeInUp;">
                        <div class="member-thumb">
                            <img src="img/team/member-3.png" alt="Team Member" class="img-responsive">
                            <figcaption class="overlay">
                                <h5>voluptatem quia voluptas </h5>
                                <p>sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit,</p>
                                <ul class="social-links text-center">
                                    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                                    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                                    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </figcaption>
                        </div>
                        <h4>Steve Flaulkin</h4>
                        <span>Sr. UI Designer</span>
                    </figure>
                    <!-- end single member -->
                    
                    <!-- single member -->
                    <figure class="team-member col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 text-center wow fadeInUp animated animated" data-wow-duration="500ms" data-wow-delay="900ms" style="visibility: visible; animation-duration: 500ms; animation-delay: 900ms; animation-name: fadeInUp;">
                        <div class="member-thumb">
                            <img src="img/team/member-1.png" alt="Team Member" class="img-responsive">
                            <figcaption class="overlay">
                                <h5>voluptatem quia voluptas </h5>
                                <p>sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit,</p>
                                <ul class="social-links text-center">
                                    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                                    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                                    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </figcaption>
                        </div>
                        <h4>John Filmr Doe</h4>
                        <span>Managing Director</span>
                    </figure>
                    <!-- end single member -->
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```